# Replace a text in a text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I am trying to replace text in a text file (let's just call the file test.txt), here is the example text:

```
Math is good
Math is hard
Learn good math
be good at math
DO\SOMETHING\NOW
```

I want something like:

```
Math is good
Math is hard
Learn good science
be good at science
DO\SOMETHING\NOW
```

I am trying to use fileinput in the following way

```
import fileinput
file = fileinput.input("Path/To/File/text.txt", inplace=True)
for line in file:
    print(line.replace("math", "science"))
```

The problem is that the print function automatically attaches "\n" so it skips a new line. I tried replacing with using "sys.stdout.write(line.replace("math", "science")) but that outputed numbers in the text file. So how do I do this efficiently so that I get the results I want. Should I just use open and go line by line and checking if the word "math" pops up and replace the word? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Actually it does change my file, so I don't think I need a temp file. Thanks for commenting though!

Comment: Ahh sorry. I didn't see the fileinput part :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell `print()` not to write a newline by setting the `end` keyword argument to an empty string:

```
print(line.replace("math", "science"), end='')
```

The [default value for `end` is `'\n'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

Alternatively you could remove the newline from `line`:

```
print(line.rstrip('\n').replace("math", "science"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked :) ... the first option, I haven't tried the second option but that is probably good to know both!